# Mocking generic scala method in mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I'm working on a Scala project using Mockito as mocking framework. I wanted to mock the following generic Scala method:

```
def parseXml[T: ClassTag](xmlUrl: URL, xsdUrl: Option[URL]): Option[T]
```

When mocking i assumed i could use on of Mockito's matchers like so:

```
when(xmlFileUnmarshallerMock.parseXml[org.mockito.Matchers.any[AddressBook]](org.mockito.Matchers.any[URL], org.mockito.Matchers.any[Option[URL]]))
    .thenReturn(Some(defaultAddressBook))
```

But it won't compile, then i tried both using [Any] and [AddressBook], but both results in the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:  Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is that your `parseXml` function actually takes three arguments, not two, that's what the `T : ClassTag` syntax is shorthand for:

```
def parseXml[T](xmlUrl: URL, xsdUrl: Option[URL])(implicit classTag: ClassTag[T]): Option[T]
```

When you are trying to mock it, scala implicitly supplies the third parameter, but mockito does not accept it, because it doesn't allow mixing matchers and non-matches in the same stubbing call.

The bottom line is, that you have to provide the third parameter explicitly, and make it a matcher:

```
when(parseXml[AddressBook](any, any)(any))
  .thenReturn(Some(defaultAddressBook))
```