# mocking generic method using Mockito and Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I'm trying to write a test for the following function in Finatra HttpClient.

```
def executeJson[T: Manifest](
    request: Request,
    expectedStatus: Status = Status.Ok): Future[T] = {...}
```

According to another question answered on StackOverflow. [mocking generic scala method in mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013764/mocking-generic-scala-method-in-mockito). This is a shorthand for:

```
def executeJson[T](
    request: Request, 
    expectedStatus: Status = Status.Ok)
    (implicit T: Manifest[T]): Futuren[T] = {...}
```

So I tried,

```
verify(httpClientMock, times(1)).executeJson[JiraProject]
    (argThat(new RequestMatcher(req)))(Matchers.any())
```

Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. I still got the following error.

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at org.specs.mock.MockitoStubs$class.argThat(Mockito.scala:331)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

I also tried `Matchers.eq(Manifest[JiraProject])`, it complains that `value Manifest of type scala.reflect.ManifestFactory.type does not take type parameters`.

I'm new to Scala and Mockito, is there anything I did wrong or I misunderstood?

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Found out the problem! So the executeJson actually takes 3 params- request, expectedStatus, and a Manifest. However, because expectedStatus is an optional, I didn't explicit pass it, that's why it complained. So, the final code should be `verify(httpClientMock, times(1)).executeJson[JiraProject](argThat(new RequestMatcher(req)), Matchers.any[Status])(Matchers.any())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using equality in the first parameter and matcher for the second one. Try using matchers for all arguments.

But a bigger problem that I feel here is that you're trying to mock 3rd party library - **this is something you should avoid**. This would also solve your problem. Here's some extra read about it - [TDD best practices: don't mock others](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2012/04/01/tdd-best-practices-dont-mock-others/)

Comment: Yea, I think you're right about that I should avoid mocking a 3rd party library.